# What does ''times'' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this sentence mean? 
''I need us to maybe put times aside that I can count on.''
If ''times'' means ''the circumstances and ideas of the present age'' What can he count on?

Comment: Context is everything. Where did this quote come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of that dialogue (Created for Connection: The "Hold Me Tight" Guide for Christian Couples, by Sue Johnson, Kenneth Sanderfer),

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=lP8rDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT193&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U3XcIYtbpG6nG_Of_MIysmXlz9aZg&w=1280

*putting times aside* is about **saving time for a special purpose** (making love there, so scheduling for that - so she could *count on* specific time periods, *times*).

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-sth-aside

Comment: it doesn't feel like very good english

Answer (score 1):

In relation to a schedule or planning, *times* refers to *time slots* or *time periods*, as in

> When are a few times you’re available for lunch?

Although in plural form, the question above typically seeks to coordinate schedules for a single lunch appointment.

In contrast, *keeping with the times* or *keeping up with the times* refers to staying stylish, fashionable, or modern and is the meaning you referenced in your question. Perhaps ironically, this construct is a bit dated and old fashioned.